# libgdx: getCell() method returns null

Tags: java, libgdx

Method layer.getCell() returns null even though there is a tile in the cell, I don't understand why the method is returning null to me

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("levels/level-1.tmx");
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get("font");
System.out.println((TiledMapTileLayer.Cell)layer.getCell(0, 0));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting the "font" layer? Not the layer with blocks? There is no font entry at 0,0.

Try "screen" or "layer-1" for your `getLayers` call.